# Is there any Windows Azure Local Development environment?

Tags: .net, windows, sdk, azure, testing

I remember I stumbled upon a page once that said Microsoft has released an application that allows you to test your client applications for windows azure locally.

The application would act as mock windows azure environment and you could use local end points for connecting to it. Does anyone know which application is it or what is its name?

I can't find it on google. I'm sure someone has used it.

Comment: All links in all current answers are dead. How do we flag this question as needing new answers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, with the Azure SDK, you're installing what is called a "local fabric" which allows you to create and test your Visual Studio apps in a local environment before posting them out into the cloud.

Google for "local fabric" or "development fabric" [**EDIT:** since SDK 1.3 the fabric is called "Compute Emulator", the Development Storage is renamed to "Storage Emnulator"] - I remember several blog posts on this, at least one by Scott Guthrie.

- [Windows Azure Tools Development Fabric and Storage Integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203061.aspx)
- [The Azure Fabric and the Development Fabric](http://azure.snagy.name/blog/?p=84)
- [Development Fabric and Development Storage](http://www.azure-forum.net/default.aspx?g=posts&t=34)

Marc

Comment: The first two links are dead.

Answer (score 3):

Azure SDK - which you can install using [Web Platform Installer tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/jnak/archive/2009/09/24/installing-the-windows-azure-tools-using-the-web-platform-installer.aspx) - 
the dev fabric provides you with a dev environment that plugs right intovisual studio for you to debug and test.
You can [download the SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8d75d4f7-77a4-4adf-bce8-1b10608574bb&displaylang=en) from

there is also an [Azure training kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=413E88F8-5966-4A83-B309-53B7B77EDF78&displaylang=en) which has a lot of hands of labs, presentations and learning material.