# How to simulate an windows azure system at local?

Tags: azure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any Windows Azure Local Development environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550523/is-there-any-windows-azure-local-development-environment)

Hi all.
I want to develop some applications which save data on windows azure but I don't want to purchase Windows Azure account now. Could you tell me how I can setup an simulated Windows Azure at local?

thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to purchase a real account to experiment with Azure. The toolkit will provide you with a simulated environment for your development. See this link to download the sdk & tools:

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/getstarted/default.aspx

Comment: does the toolkit support pas services like event hub, event grid, etc?